# Hacer binding en Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding

estoy creando una aplicación en Xamarin.Forms. No logro pasar el Binding ChatterCount en Xamarin Forms, ya que solo obtengo una página en blanco, ademas la aplicacion se detiene si escribo el siguiente código:

```
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <paralelo:Page1/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Además cual sería la forma correcta de hacer el Binding? para  public List Viewers { get; set; } ?  ya que si bien es una colección tampoco logro que XMAL logre reconocerla.

TwitchJson.cs: Es es mi clase

````
```
namespace Paralelo
{
    public partial class TwitchJson
    {
        [JsonProperty("_links", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Links Links { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("chatter_count", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int ChatterCount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("chatters", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Chatters Chatters { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Chatters
    {
        [JsonProperty("broadcaster", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<string> Broadcaster { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("vips", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<object> Vips { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("moderators", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<string> Moderators { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("staff", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<object> Staff { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("admins", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<object> Admins { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("global_mods", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<object> GlobalMods { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("viewers", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<string> Viewers { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Viewers.ToString();
        }
    }
    public partial class Links
    {
    }
    
    
    public partial class TwitchJson
    {
        public static TwitchJson FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwitchJson> 
  (json, Paralelo.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this TwitchJson self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Paralelo.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
         
}
```
````

PAGE1.XMAL.CS Aquí está todo mi código

````
```
    namespace Paralelo
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
      
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            
            string url = @"http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/nashoinferno/chatters";

            // OBTENIENDO EL JSON    
            TwitchJson twitchJson;
            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                var json = webClient.DownloadString(url);

                twitchJson = TwitchJson.FromJson(json);
            }

           
            listview.ItemsSource =  twitchJson.ChatterCount.ToString();
            

            //DISPLAY DE LOS ESPECTADORES

            /* foreach (string espectador in twitchJson.ChatterCount.ToString())
            {

                listview.ItemsSource = espectador;  
            }*/

        }
      
             } 
    }
```
````

PAGE1.XMAL Aqui está el XMAL que no logro que reconozca

```
     <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:paralelo="clr-namespace:Paralelo"
                  x:Class="Paralelo.Page1"
                  BackgroundColor="White">
         <ContentPage.BindingContext>
             <paralelo:Page1/>
         </ContentPage.BindingContext>
         <ListView x:Name="listview">
 
         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <TextCell TextColor="black" Text="{Binding ChatterCount}"/>
 
             </DataTemplate>
             
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 
     </ListView>
            
 </ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para comenzar tu listview recibe un listado de objetos y tu le estas pasando un solo objeto, y no como listado,

```
  listview.ItemsSource =  twitchJson.ChatterCount.ToString(); // mal

  listview.ItemsSource =  twitchJson.Cheaters.Broadcaster;
```

En tu Xaml le estas diciendo que dentro de tu template te tome la propiedad `ChatterCount`, pero esa propiedad tampoco esta dentro de un objeto List o array, etc.

De esta manera tu listview deberia funcionar porque le estas pasando un array de string en el ejemplo que te deje.

El `BindingContext` en este caso no lo estas necesitando porque le estas pasando desde c# directamente al itemsource del listview, atraves de CodeBehind en lugar de MVVM.

De ejemplo si quisieras usar el template tendria que ser algo asi.

//Archivo persona

```
 public class Persona
 {
   public string nombre {get;set;}
   public string apellido {get;set;}
 }
```

//Codebehind

```
 List<Persona> Personas = new List<Personas>(); //rellenas con personas
 
 listview.ItemsSource =  Personas;
```

//Xaml

```
  <ListView x:Name="listview">

     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextCell TextColor="black" Text="{Binding nombre}" Description="{Binding apellido}"/>

         </DataTemplate>
         
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```